# How to import ics file into mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, icalendar

I want to import data from an ics file published using MS-outlook into mysql.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
$filename = "test.tsv";
//Read the file
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
//Split file into lines
$lines  = explode("\n", $content);

//Find columns by reading first line
$columns = explode("\t", $lines[0]);

//Construct create table
$sql_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tsv` (\n";
//Set first column ID
$sql_table .= "  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n";
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    //Add each column to the string as type text
    $sql_table .= "  `".addslashes($column)."` text NOT NULL,\n";
}
$sql_table .= "  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;";
```